# Typescript strictNullChecks syntax

Tags: typescript, lodash

I'm using the `strictNullChecks` flag in my Typescript project.

Consider the function below:

```
function hello(a: string | null) {
  if (a !== null) {
    console.log(a.length); // Here, "a" can only be a string
  }
}
```

The compiler works perfectly here.

However if I write instead `if (typeof a !== "null")` or even lodash's `if (!_.isNull(a))` the compiler won't understand and will complain that `a` can possibly be `null`.

Is there any way to have these alternative syntaxes work too?

Comment: Did you realy read out what this compiler flag does? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: Also: `typeof (a = null) === "object"` [_for legacy reasons_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null#Difference_between_null_and_undefined)

Comment: The lodash typings have been updated and `if (!_.isNull(a))` should do a proper type guard now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However if I write instead `if (typeof a !== "null")` or ... the compiler won't understand and will complain that a can possibly be null.

This is a good thing because `typeof null === "object"`, not `"null"`. TypeScript does not consider non-working ways of testing for `null` to be correct.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that `if (typeof a !== "null")` is not a good approach. I guess I'll use `a !== null` from now on.